# Linq to Sql - Count, sub-query and subtraction

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am trying to convert the following T-SQL statement into **Linq to Sql**  but am having trouble with the subtraction from the count. The final select will be a single row and single column (int)

I have done the SQL in two ways (sub-query and by JOIN/GROUP) which both return the same result, although I think the former might be the 'easier' option...

**SQL 1 using a sub-query...**

```
SELECT  e.Places - ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Event Participants] ep WHERE ep.E__ID = x AND ep.EP_STAT IN ('B','C')) AS AvailablePlaces
 From Events e
 WHERE e.E__ID = x
```

**SQL 2 using GROUP BY and JOIN...**

```
SELECT  e.Places -  COUNT(ep.E__ID) AS AvailablePlaces
 FROM Events e
 JOIN [Event Participants] ep  ON e.E__ID = ep.E__ID
 WHERE e.E__ID = x AND ep.EP_STAT IN ('B','C') 
 GROUP BY  e.Places
```

Comment: Linq to Sql? Really?

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
var array = new string[] { "B", "C" };

var result = (from e in Event where e.E__ID == x 
                 let count = (from ep in Event_Participants 
                              where ep.E__ID == e.E__ID && 
                              array.Contains(ep.EP_Stat) 
                              select ep).Count()

                 select   e.Places - count
              )
              .Single();
```

Depending on your model, it might be possible to use navigation properties in the subquery.